# Can I graft fruit trees without pruning?

Tags: fruit-trees, fruits, grafting, branches

I just got some apple, peach and pear trees. They're still kind of young but I'm wondering if i can just graft an extra branch on the side without cutting any of the ones it has (only has 2-3 thin ones).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sure you can add a [bud graft](http://www.ehow.com/how_2051060_bud-graft-fruit-tree.html) anywhere, but you generally want to prune the branch that you are grafting to, so the bud is stimulated to grow.

Comment: That's the thing, i just got these trees, they might be around 6ft and have just a few branches, im guessing i should wait then?

Comment: You can try... But branches and grafting are like money and gambling, don't risk what you aren't willing to lose :)

Comment: lol excellent reference :) part time player as well :D